# Parts of the expression are evaluated well, but not the whole expression together

Tags: matrix, evaluation, pattern-matching, quaternions

I have the following code inended to define quaternions:

```
Unprotect[Power];
Power[0, 0] = 1;
Protect[Power];
Unprotect[Dot];
Dot[x_, y_?NumberQ] := x y;
Dot[x_?NumberQ, y_] := x y;
Dot[Matrix[x_], Matrix[y_]] := Matrix[x . y]
Protect[Dot];
Unprotect[Plus];
Matrix[x_] + Matrix[y_] ^= Matrix[x + y];
Protect[Plus];
Unprotect[Times];
x_?NumericQ Matrix[y_] ^= Matrix[x y];
Matrix[y_] x_?NumericQ ^= Matrix[x y];
Protect[Times];
$Post = # /. i -> Matrix[( {
            {I, 0},
            {0, -I}
           } )] /. j -> Matrix[( {
           {0, 1},
           {-1, 0}
          } )] /. k -> Matrix[( {
          {0, I},
          {I, 0}
         } ) ] /. 
     f_[Matrix[mat_], args___] :> 
      Matrix[MatrixFunction[f[#, args] &, mat]] /. 
    Matrix[{{a_, c_}, {d_, b_}}] -> 
     Re[a] + Im[a] i + Re[c] j + Im[c] k &;
```

It correctly evauates `Log[k]` to `k Pi/2` and correctly evaluates `j . k Pi/2` to `i Pi/2`. But it cannot evaluate `j Log[k]`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `FullSimplify` to `$Post` fixes the problem:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Unprotect[Power];
Power[0, 0] = 1;
Protect[Power];
Unprotect[Dot];
Dot[x_, y_?NumberQ] := x y;
Dot[x_?NumberQ, y_] := x y;
Protect[Dot];
Matrix /: Dot[Matrix[x_], Matrix[y_]] := Matrix[x . y];
Matrix /: Matrix[x_] + Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x + y];
Matrix /: x_?NumericQ Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x y];
Matrix /: Matrix[y_] x_?NumericQ := Matrix[x y];
Matrix /: Matrix[x_]*Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x . y] /; x . y == y . x;
Matrix /: Re[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ]] := Tr[x]/Length[x];

$Post = FullSimplify[# /. i -> Matrix[( {
             {I, 0},
             {0, -I}
            } )] /. j -> Matrix[( {
            {0, 1},
            {-1, 0}
           } )] /. k -> Matrix[( {
           {0, I},
           {I, 0}
          } ) ] /. 
      f_[Matrix[mat_], args___] :> 
       Matrix[MatrixFunction[f[#, args] &, mat]] /. 
     Matrix[{{a_, c_}, {d_, b_}}] -> 
      Re[a] + Im[a] i + Re[c] j + Im[c] k ] &;
```